# What can I say about matrix A, if both A and I-A are positive semidefinite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-semidefinite

What can I say about matrix $A$, if both $A$ and $I-A$ are positive semidefinite? For example, is it a projection matrix then?

Comment: $A=\frac12I$ works, but it isn't a projection matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can say $A$ is a hermitian matrix (or symmetric, in the real case) whose eigenvalues are all in the interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: Thanks! Any pointer on how to prove this?

Comment: @hmi Once we know that A is symmetric it is sufficient to consider a basis of eigenvectors and observe  that if $Av=\lambda v\implies (I-A)v=v-\lambda v$ and $v^TAv=\lambda v^Tv \implies v^T(I-A)v=v^Tv-\lambda v^Tv=(1-\lambda) v^Tv$ and PSD requires that $\lambda \ge 0$ and $(1-\lambda)\ge 0$.

Comment: @hmi But honestly I can't se why it is necessarly symmetric (or hermitian) :(

Comment: @gimusi It's slightly eccentric to describe a non-Hermitian/symmetric matrix as positive (semi)definite.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Thus we are assuming that it is symmetric since the skew part is not relevant?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Thus A in necessarly symmetric? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have already got some good answers, but I would like to add one more thing,

Also $\bf I-A$ will have pairwise eigenvalues $\lambda_k({\bf I-A}) = 1-\lambda_k({\bf A})$ so they will be each others spectral complementaries in the sense that $$\min_{\bf v}\left\{\bf \|Av\| + \|(I-A)(v+d)\|\right\}$$ will pull $\bf v$ in different directions (either towards $\bf 0$ or $\bf -d$) linearly weighted according to the $\lambda_k({\bf A})$s.